# How to initializeApp in HuaWei android messaging service

Tags: firebase, huawei-mobile-services

In FirebaseApp, there is a initializeApp method to provide it's constants for firebase app. How about the related method in android app using HMS service?

Comment: hi,Huawei don't need a unified initialization.

Comment: Could provide more detail about why hms not need class like FirebaseApp.

Comment: hi@ccd,The AGC plug-in writes the parameters of the AGC into the APP in String format during compilation. Each kit is automatically initialized before calling the API. And now firebase does not require unified initialization either.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, HMS does not provide a unified codebased initialization, however, some kits individually do support codebased initialization by requesting APIkeys.